# Can not display echo value properly by comparing two array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I need to display some `echo` value by comparing two array using PHP. I am providing my code below.

```
$maindata=array(array('id'=>3),array('id'=>7),array('id'=>9));
 $childata=array(array('id'=>3),array('id'=>45),array('id'=>7),array('id'=>123));
    for($i=0;$i < count($childata);$i++){
        if(in_array($childata[$i],$maindata)){
            echo "get the value \n".$maindata[$i]['id'];
            echo "delete the value \n".$maindata[$i]['id'];
            echo "insert the value \n".$maindata[$i]['id'];
        }
        if(!in_array($childata[$i],$maindata)){
             echo "delete the value \n".$childata[$i]['id'];
        }
    }
```

Here my requirement is if any data from first array (`$maindata`) is present in second array (`i.e-$childata`) then the first `three echo message` will display and other value from second array (`i.e-$childata`) the second `only one echo message` will display. But in some cases it is not working like below.

**Cases:**

```
$maindata=array(array('id'=>3),array('id'=>7),array('id'=>9));
 $childata=array(array('id'=>3),array('id'=>45),array('id'=>123));


               or

$maindata=array(array('id'=>3),array('id'=>7),array('id'=>9));
 $childata=array(array('id'=>3),array('id'=>45));
```

The first case from above I need for all value from  `$maindata` array the first `three echo message` will display and for `array('id'=>45) and array('id'=>123)` the `only last one echo message` will display. Similarly for the second case from above  all value from  `$maindata` array the first `three echo message` will display and for `array('id'=>45)` the `only last one echo message` will display.

Answer (score 0):

The test `if (count($maindata) < count($childata)) {` is false for your 2 last examples.

I suggest you remove this test.

Comment: @satya: What do you want to solve, doesn't it work now? Please edit your question and show explicitely what you get vs what you're expecting for each test case.

Comment: @ Toto : Its working for only if second array length  is greater than first.

Comment: @satya: Please edit your question and show explicitely what you get vs what you're expecting for each test case.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be good enough:

```
$maindata=array(array('id'=>3),array('id'=>7),array('id'=>9));
$childata=array(array('id'=>3),array('id'=>45),array('id'=>7),array('id'=>123));


foreach($childata as $key => $value){
    if(in_array($value, $maindata[$key])){
        echo "get the value \n".$childata[$key]['id'];
        echo "delete the value \n".$childata[$key]['id'];
        echo "insert the value \n".$childata[$key]['id'];
    } else {
        echo "delete the value \n".$childata[$key]['id'];
    }
}
```